# Why is an array in $localStorage working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

`index.html`

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <form >
      <tags options="{addable: true}" typeahead-options="typeaheadOpts" data-model="information.address" data-src="toPerson as toPerson for toPerson in to"></tags>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" style="width:95%;" data-ng-model = "information.subject"><br />
      <textarea style="width:95%;" rows="10" data-ng-model = "information.emailContent"></textarea>
   </form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
   <a href="#" class="btn" ng-click = "submit(information.address, information.subject, information.emailContent); close()">Close</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click = "close()">Send</a>
</div>
```

`emailViewController.js`

```
$scope.information = {
      address: [],
      subject: []
   };

$scope.submit = function (address, subject, emailContent) {
   $localStorage.address.push(address);

   if (! ($localStorage.subject instanceof Array) ) {
      $localStorage.subject = [];
   }

   $localStorage.subject.push(subject);
```

If I don't initialize `$localStorage.subject` as an array, it gives me an error that says `.push is not a function`.

Why does it not give this error when I push data to `$localStorage.address`?

Comment: Is it possible that you initialized `$localStorage.address` in some other part of your application?

Comment: No. I am positive I did not. @DarinDimitrov

Comment: Can you try clearing all data from localstorage and then see if the variables will be automatically initialized. Maybe there's some value for `address` in the local storage of the browser which could explain why it is initialized.

Comment: I have tried that. When I clear `$localStorage`, and try to push data into the `$localStorage.address` array, it gives me an error that the length of the array is not known. I think this is caused because `$localStorage.address` is not initialized as an array anywhere. My question however, is that how am I able to push data into `$localStorage.address` in the first place. For example, if I alter my code as follows in `$scope.submit()`, `$localStorage.address = address` works, but `$localStorage.subject = subject` does not work. @DarinDimitrov

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```
var Helper = {
    pushArray: function (arr1, arr2) {
        arr1 = this.toArray(arr1);
        if (arr1 && arr2 && Array.isArray(arr1)) {
            arr1.push.apply(arr1, Array.isArray(arr2) ? arr2 : [arr2]);
        }
    },

    toArray: function (arr) {
        return arr ? (Array.isArray(arr) ? arr : [arr]) : [];
    }
};
Helper.pushArray(arr1, second);
```

or you just declare:

```
$localStorage.$default({
   subject: []
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful. My question however, is that how am I able to push data into `$localStorage.address` without initializing it as an array.

Comment: ok. if (!$localStorage.address) {$localStorage.address=data; }else{$localStorage.address.push(data);}

Comment: Yeah. I understand that logic. The code I posted is working perfectly. What I don't understand is why it is working. My question is how is the data being pushed to `$localStorage.address` without initialising it as an array?